# Is There A Method To Detect Switch In Button Selection Via Holding?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

This may sound confusing, but those who are using Windows Phone, please launch any keyboard capable applications and hold your finger over a letter, then shift your finger around. That event. Is there any way to develop that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set Button to Hover Mode.

   `Button btn = new Button
   {
       ClickMode = ClickMode.Hover
   };`
2. Set events.

   `btn.MouseEnter += (sender, e) => { 
       //What happens when your finger reaches within the area of the button. 
   };`

   `btn.MouseLeave += (sender, e) => { //What happens when your finger leaves the area of the button. };`